# Select items in a list with keyup JavaScript, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a list to select items but the behavior when I use up or down arrow is not so good. When I use up or down arrows it scrolls the `<div>` and also select and focus on `<li>` tag but the scrolls moves first so it seems to be kind of rare.

How can I achieve the correct behavior using up and down key?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        ul {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        background: aqua;
        overflow: scroll;           
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        $(function(){
            num = ""

            $("body").keyup(function(e){

                if (e.keyCode == 40){

                    $("ul").find('li:eq('+num+')').focus().css('color', 'red');
                    console.log(num ++)

                }

                if (e.keyCode == 38){

                    $("ul").find('li:eq('+num+')').focus().css('color', 'blue');
                    console.log(num --)

                }   


            })

        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>



</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Please clarify what you think the problem is and what the desired behavior should be.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem exactly, but I will try to help you.
For this solution that I have prepared for you.
Let me know if you did not mean it!

```js
$(function() {
    var num = 0;

    $("body").keyup(function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          var elementIndex = $("li:focus").index();
          $("ul > li").eq(elementIndex).css('color', 'red');
          console.log("Last focused element index: " + elementIndex + " has change to: " + Math.floor(elementIndex + 1));
          $("ul > li").eq(elementIndex + 1).focus();
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
          var elementIndex = $("li:focus").index();
          $("ul > li").eq(elementIndex).css('color', 'blue');
          if(elementIndex == 0) return;
          console.log("Last focused element index: " + elementIndex + " has change to: " + Math.floor(elementIndex - 1));
          $("ul > li").eq(elementIndex - 1).focus();
        }


    })

})
```

```css
ul {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        background: aqua;
        overflow: scroll;           
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li tabindex="0">Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>
    <li tabindex="0" >Palabra Palabra Palabra Palabra</li>



</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really apreciate your help Maciej Wojtasik, no, what I mean just look the behavior of the scroll bar when you type up or down, look this site kwfinder.com and try to chose a language, just move the up an down key arrows and see how the scroll bar moves, and se my example and your example, thats the problem and I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: @Elarquitecto I also found an interesting solution on this page:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/listbox/listbox-scrollable.html
Maybe it will be useful to you!